# Oracle 12c RAC : Start / Stop SCAN Listener one by one

Tags: oracle

On 12c, I understand following command can stop single SCAN Listener;
srvctl stop scan_listener -scannumber 1

May I ask if we can not specify by the node name or netnum like on 11g ?
Ex.
srvctl stop scan_listener -i 2

And sorry for silly question, but how can get to know the right scannumber or netnum of each scan listner?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it explicitly, but you could do in two phases

```
srvctl status scan_listener | egrep 'running.*xxx'
```

where xxx is the node name in question, to get a listing of the running listeners and the nodes they are on, then a little awk etc to isolate the listener in question